# Angularjs $http delete with $q promise leads to TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-promise, angular-http

The following snippet returns the following error: `TypeError: object is not a function`

```
service.deleteItem = function(itemId) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    $http.delete(SERVER_REST_PATH + '/items/' + itemId)
        .success(function() {
            def.resolve();
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            def.reject("Error deleting the item");
        });
    return def.promise();
};
```

If I rewrite it as the following it works:

```
service.deleteItem = function(itemId) {
    return $http.delete(SERVER_REST_PATH + '/items/' + itemId);
};
```

All other $http methods that I use(i.e GET, PUT, POST) in my app are wrapped with the $q the same way and they don't have this issue. Only the DELETE is causing this issue. When I debug it it just skips the $http's success(), error() and then() methods. I'm using angular version 1.3.13.

Comment: How do you use `service.deleteProfile`? Share the code where you call this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `return def.promise();` to `return def.promise`;

example :

```
function deferredTimer(success) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $timeout(function() {
    if (success) {
      deferred.resolve({ message: "This is great!" });
    } else {
      deferred.reject({ message: "Really bad" });
    }
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Just didn't saw it. Looking everywhere but not this. Working during the weekend is no good ;) Thanks!

Comment: i had also made same mistake.. so thats the first thing i checked :)